# Check if UserA and UserB exists in the username column

Tags: mysql

This is code:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='userA' AND username='userB';
```

I want to know if these two users exist in the username column
It should return TRUE

Comment: Username can't be `userA` and `userB` at __same__ time. You have to think again about your task.

Comment: You might play with the idea of `username='userA' OR username='userB'` thats quite possible. It wont return true (its not a function) but it will return 1 or 2 `id` values. If you want to know which ones exist, add `username` to the select list

Comment: All I want is to know if the two users exists. That's my problem

Comment: You were given a possible solution in the previous comment. Use `OR` and count returned rows.

Comment: Thank you. but, I'm just a beginner. Can I get a sample code?

Comment: Username can't be userA and userB at same time. You have to think again about your task.

Comment: Username can't be userA and userB at same time **in the same row**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='userA') 
     * EXISTS (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='userB')
```

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT username) = 2
FROM users
WHERE username IN ('userA', 'userB')
```

Both queries will return `1` if both usernames exists and `0` otherwise.

Comment: Let me check it out

Comment: Thank you @Akina. The first query gave me exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` to get a True/False value for the existence of a record matching certain conditions:

`EXISTS(SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='userA') AND EXISTS(SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='userB')`

Comment: All I want is to know if the two users exists. That's my problem. Give any solution to get this working

Comment: I don't want to check if userA exists or userB. Check if both exists or not. Please...

Comment: 1st variant will give TRUE if either (only one, not both) username exists. 2ns variant will give TRUE even if 2 rows with the one username and none with another one exists.